# Execute INSERT if table is empty?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to do an insert under a count condition, something like:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (colname) VALUES('foo') IF COUNT(my_table) < 1
```

Basically I want to insert a single default record if the table is currently empty. I'm using mysql.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use SELECT instead of VALUES to be able to expand the query with a WHERE clause.

EXISTS is a better & faster test than COUNT

```
INSERT INTO my_table (colname)
SELECT 'foo'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM my_table)
```

Comment: You may need to use the dummy table **DUAL** to get this to work. `INSERT INTO my_table (colname)
SELECT 'foo' FROM DUAL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM my_table)`

Comment: INSERT INTO my_table (colname) SELECT 'foo' FROM (SELECT 'bar') AS Bar  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM my_table) -- inline dummy table

Comment: @SandeepGB Inline table completely unrequired. This is MySQL, not Oracle

Comment: Why do I need the first `SELECT`?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to place a unique key on a column.  Then execute a [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html):

```
REPLACE [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED]
    [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
```

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT,
>   except that if an old row in the table
>   has the same value as a new row for a
>   PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old
>   row is deleted before the new row is
>   inserted

Comment: +1: I was just going to write something like this when your answer popped up. :) An alternative to REPLACE is to use INSERT IGNORE, which will produce a warning (rather than an error) when the statement fails to execute.

Comment: See also `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

Answer (score 1):

This is easier to read:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (colname) 
SELECT 'foo' FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM my_table);
```

The lack of a `VALUES` is mitigated by the `SELECT FROM DUAL` which will provide the values. the `FROM DUAL` is not always required, but it doesn't hurt to include it for that weird configurations where it is required (like the installation of Percona I am using).

The `NOT EXISTS` is faster than doing a count which can be slow on a table with a large number of rows.

Comment: What kind of performance hit is there doing that sub query? Would it be better to just do an insert and catch the error if it exists?

Comment: The performance hit would depend on if any indexes were used. From a readability and maintenance POV, doing a SELECT and then doing the insert if the row doesn't exist is probably better, just because this kind of query is just weird.  I also wouldn't want to do the INSERT IGNORE just because it seems like you're asking for triage headaches down the road.