# Execute mysql insert only if table is empty

Tags: mysql

Following this question, I've been trying to mimic the correct answer to insert data in my table only if it is empty.

[Execute INSERT if table is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307164/execute-insert-if-table-is-empty)

This is my code:

```
INSERT INTO `statuses` SELECT 
    ('Something', 'Something else', 123),
    ('Something', 'Something else', 234)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `statuses`);
```

But instead of adding the elements if the table is empty, I just get:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `statuses`)'
```

How exactly am I supposed to write the query so that the values are inserted only if the table is empty?

Comment: First of all it should be VALUES instead of the first SELECT.

Comment: the top answer in the linked question says differently. I was trying to copy the code posted: it tells not to use VALUES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your statement:

```
INSERT INTO `statuses`
    (SELECT  'Something', 'Something else', 123
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `statuses`)
    ) union all
    (SELECT 'Something', 'Something else', 234
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `statuses`)
    );
```

You need to repeat the `where` twice in this case, once for each subquery.  You can also do:

```
INSERT INTO `statuses`
    select t.*
    from ((SELECT  'Something' as col1, 'Something else' as col2, 123 as col3
          ) union all
          (SELECT 'Something', 'Something else', 234
          )
         ) t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `statuses`);
```

In this version, you need to assign names to the columns.

Or, you could just use two separate insert statements.

Comment: the first one is giving me this error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `statuses`) union all SELECT 'Something', '' at line 3"

Comment: @Saturnix ...  The only thing I can think of is a parsing problem.  I added parentheses to prevent that.  In practice, I usually put `union` statements in the `from` clause, as in the second query.

Comment: the first one still doesn't work (same error as before) but the second works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

correct syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO user_authentication
SELECT t.*
FROM ((SELECT 1 as col1, 'kingston' as col2, 'test' as col3, true as col4)) t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_authentication);
```

This is working for me.