# Execute INSERT multiple values if table is empty POSTGRES

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to add some default values in a postgres table. I can add one value but I want to add 5 default values. I've tried this below but it creates only one value since after inserting the first value the empty condition is no longer valid.

```
records_to_insert = [( 1,'foo', 30, 2, True),
                   ( 2,'bar', 60, 3, False),
                   ( 3,'hero', 95, 2, False),
                   ( 4,'borth', 45, 1, True),
                   ( 5,'here', 30, 2, True)]
sql_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO tester (id, name, time, rating,others)
                SELECT %s,%s,%s,%s,%s
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tester) """
cursor = connection.cursor()
#executemany() to insert 3 rows
result  = cursor.executemany(sql_insert_query, records_to_insert)
```

I am using python3 and postgres10.5. I've also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307164/execute-insert-if-table-is-empty), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941928/mysql-insert-if-table-is-empty) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605985/execute-mysql-insert-only-if-table-is-empty) but no dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cur, sql, argslist, template=None, page_size=100)`](http://psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values)

> Execute a statement using VALUES with a sequence of parameters.
> Parameters:
>
> - cur – the cursor to use to execute the query.
> - sql – the query to execute. It must contain a single %s placeholder, which will be replaced by a VALUES list. (...)

You should reformulate the query to use `VALUES`:

```
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values

sql_insert_query = """ 
    INSERT INTO tester (id, name, time, rating, others)
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES %s) s
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tester) """
execute_values(cursor, sql_insert_query, records_to_insert)
```