# SQL - Insert into table if doesn't have data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm using MYSQL script and I want to insert some values in a table.

```
INSERT INTO `testType` (`name`) VALUES ('URL');
INSERT INTO `testType` (`name`) VALUES ('xD');
INSERT INTO `testType` (`name`) VALUES ('LOL');
```

But I only want to insert if the table is empty in the first place.

I'm not a SQL guy but basically

```
if(testType.length() == 0 {

    INSERT INTO `testType` (`name`) VALUES ('URL');
    INSERT INTO `testType` (`name`) VALUES ('xD');
    INSERT INTO `testType` (`name`) VALUES ('LOL');

}
```

How can I do this the simplest and smallest way possible? Thank you.

EDIT: my question is different. I want to insert ALL THE DATA if the table is empty. not only one insert at the time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute INSERT if table is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307164/execute-insert-if-table-is-empty)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL - Insert If Table is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941928/mysql-insert-if-table-is-empty)

Answer (score 2):

First, I would suggest doing this in one step:

```
INSERT INTO testType(name)
    VALUES ('URL'), ('xD'), ('LOL');
```

Then, you can express this without `IF`:

```
INSERT INTO testType(name)
    SELECT t.name
    FROM (SELECT 'URL' as name UNION ALL
          SELECT 'xD' as name UNION ALL
          SELECT 'LOL' as name
         ) t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM testType);
```

Finally, if you want to insert these values if *each* doesn't exist, then you can let the database do the work.  First, define a unique constraint/index on the `name` (if name is not already the primary key), and then use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_testtable_name ON testtable(name);

INSERT INTO testType(name)
    VALUES ('URL'), ('xD'), ('LOL')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name);
```

Comment: this add stuff to the database even tho the table is not empty.

Comment: i only want to add that insert IF the table has 0 rows

Comment: @user9674353 . . . The second query does just that.  The last makes sure that the three values that you want are all in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @ExistCount INT;
SET @ExistCount = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `testType`);

IF @ExistCount<1
THEN
    INSERT INTO `testType` (`name`) VALUES ('URL'),('xD'),('LOL');
END IF;
```

Comment: **<statement> or DELIMITER expected, got IF**

Answer (score 0):

You can use stored procedure

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `proc1` ()
BEGIN

        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO variable1 FROM testType;
        IF variable1 = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO `testType` (`name`) VALUES ('URL');
            INSERT INTO `testType` (`name`) VALUES ('xD');
            INSERT INTO `testType` (`name`) VALUES ('LOL');
    END WHILE;
END //
```