# MYSQL - Insert If Table is empty

Tags: mysql

I want to insert some data on my table if the table is empty (0 rows).

I tried this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `account_types`)
THEN
       INSERT INTO `account_types` (`type`, `group`) VALUES ('400', 'test');
       INSERT INTO `account_types` (`type`, `group`) VALUES ('401', 'test2');
END IF;
```

But I get

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `account_types`)     THEN          INSERT INTO `account_types' at line 1

What can I do ? I'm using MYSQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute INSERT if table is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307164/execute-insert-if-table-is-empty)

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO `account_types`(`type`, `group`)
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT '400' `type`, 'test' `group` UNION ALL
 SELECT '401' `type`, 'test2' `group` UNION ALL
 SELECT '402' `type`, 'test3' `group`) A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM account_types B WHERE A.type=B.type);
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1e80e/1

Comment: what if I have 3 rows to add?

Comment: Check I Edited My answer

Comment: I get this: Error Code: 1267. Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Comment: I'm using Mysql 5.7.21

Comment: Run Below Query and then try `SET collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci';`
`ALTER TABLE account_types CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

Comment: surelly there must be a better way to check if a table is empty and if it is add stuff

Comment: and your code doesn't work. if I add more selects it will add more stuff to the table even tho the table is not empty.